# Алгоритм - Сравнить силы рук игроков в покере

Tags: алгоритм

Я пишу свой симулятор покера Hold'em Texas Poker на 6 игроков. У меня возникла проблема сравнения сил рук игроков.

После Раздачи карт и объявления у кого какая рука вышла, я застопорился на алгоритме выбора чья рука сильнее. Лично я пока склоняюсь к тому, чтобы выдавать численное значение рукам, записать все руки в один массив, брать индекс с максимальным значением и тем самым выбирать победителя. Только кажется не оптимальным решением.

Всего 9 сил рук в покере:

1. Стрит-флеш
2. Каре
3. Фул-хаус
4. Флеш
5. Стрит
6. Сет (тройка)
7. Две пары
8. Пара
9. Старшая карта

Алгоритм можно написать на любом языке, лишь бы понятно было. Также можно и словами.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Т.е. джокера в этой разновидности нет?

Comment: Нет. Обычный покер, как в Джеймсе Бонде :)

Comment: В чем, собственно, проблема? Определить максимальную комбинацию у игрока, или определить игрока с максимальной комбинацией?

Comment: За столом шесть игроков. Раздаются карты по 2 каждому из игроков и 5 карт на стол. Рука игрока это 5 карт со стола + 2 его. Определяются наилучшие комбинации для каждого игрока. Теперь нужно выяснить у кого комбинация самая лучшая.
Также, если комбинации совпадают, то выяснить у кого старше ранк. Но этот вопрос я уже решил.

Comment: Вы на мой вопрос так и не ответили. Или у вас вызывают проблемы обе задачи?

Comment: Максимальную комбинацию я определяю для каждого из игроков, поэтому мне это не нужно. А вот игрок с лучшей комбинацией мне нужен.

Comment: Мой вариант с присвоением числа каждой комбинации, кажется действенным, но я пытаюсь сравнивать каждого игрока с каждым. А это затратно :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если проблема в определении игрока с максимальной комбинацией, то я бы решал задачу так

1. Поместил бы в массив для каждого игрока **структуру** с тремя полями

   1. Сила руки
   2. Старшая карта в комбинации
   3. Индекс игрока
2. Отсортировал бы массив по **двум** полям. Вначале по силе руки, а при равенстве, по старшей карте
3. Максимальный элемент в массиве будет с победившим игроком

Comment: Спасибо. При равенстве по старшей карте не совсем верно, так как там надо сравнивать карты между игроками, у которых комбинации совпадают. Потому что, например, комбинации могу совпадать по первым трём старшим картам, а различаться на четвёртой или пятой картах. Но спасибо за основной алгоритм.

Comment: @Йелекс Правильно. Именно поэтому я и говорю, что вначале сравниваем комбинации, а затем, при их равенстве, сравниваем старшие карты в комбинаци